# how to replace space with - in href with php or jquery

Tags: php, url, href

i want to replace space with - in  a tag -->href attribut in php smarty;

that a[key] is dynamic

what is the way? 
`<a href="key.php?c={$obj->a[key]}">{$obj->a[key]}</a>`

Comment: for example i have the url <<key.php?c=home and car >>but i want to show<<key.php?c=home-and-car >>

Comment: i want to change some a tags and use function for this how a bout this adia ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be answer for you

`<a href="key.php?c={$obj->a[key]|replace:' ':'-'}">{$obj-a[key]|replace:' ':'-'}</a>`

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl

Answer (score 0):

```
you should try this
```

> str_replace() is a php function which replace the character between
>   sentences. there are basically three argument pass in the function.
>   First argument: search the character, Second argument: Replacing Character,
>   Third argument: sentences.

```
<?php
$str='home and car';
echo '<a href="key.php?c='.str_replace(' ','-',$str).'">'.str_replace(' ','-',$str).'</a>';
?>
```

### output

[image]

### jquery code

> g is a regex code which replace all the space between the string.

```
<script>
$("a").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace(/ /g, "-");
    $(this).prop('href',text);
    $(this).text(text);
});
</script>
```

### Output

```
<a href="home-and-car">home-and-car</a>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it more comprehensive, and explain the important elements of the code you have included.